# CypressError: Timed out after 5000ms `cy.wait()` ...No Request ever occurred

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress, vite

I have decided to build a React app using Vite, Chakra-UI, and TypeScript with testing done in Cypress. The goal was to learn more about some of these technologies. Coincidentally, this is my first time using Cypress.

Unfortunately, I've gotten snagged on the issue regarding testing the `.wait()` in an E2E test. The error specifically reads: `CypressError: Timed out retrying after 5000ms:`cy.wait()`timed out waiting`5000ms`for the 1st request to the route:`getGames`. No request ever occurred.` I've seen a lot of advice regarding stubbing first before visiting the page and then waiting for the call. However, after multiple attempts, I just can't seem to get the wait call to NOT time out. My latest attempt has been to intercept in a before call before beforeEach-ing the visit function call. As you can see from the image I've uploaded, the intercept seems to be registered, but never increments.

Has anyone encountered this, and has a potential solution? Thank you in advance!

Cypress Console:

[image: Cypress Console]

I have a fixture defined as `games.json` which contains the following content:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt",
    "background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/crop/600/400/games/618/618c2031a07bbff6b4f611f10b6bcdbc.jpg",
    "parent_platforms": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "PC", "slug": "pc" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "PlayStation", "slug": "playstation" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "Xbox", "slug": "xbox" },
      { "id": 7, "name": "Nintendo", "slug": "nintendo" }
    ],
    "metacritic": "92"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "BioShock Infinite",
    "background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/crop/600/400/games/fc1/fc1307a2774506b5bd65d7e8424664a7.jpg",
    "parent_platforms": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "PC", "slug": "pc" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "PlayStation", "slug": "playstation" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "Xbox", "slug": "xbox" },
      { "id": 6, "name": "Linux", "slug": "linux" },
      { "id": 7, "name": "Nintendo", "slug": "nintendo" }
    ],
    "metacritic": "94"
  }
]
```

`../support/commands.ts`:

```
const baseURL = "**http://api.rawg.io/api*";

Cypress.Commands.add("landing", () => {
  cy.intercept("GET", `${baseURL}/games`, { fixture: "games.json" }).as(
    "getGames"
  );
});
```

And my test file:

```
describe("The Home Page", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.landing();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/");
  });

  it("successfully loads", () => {
    cy.wait("@getGames");
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you see in network requests? Does your app even call these api endpoints?

Comment: @nucleartux, thanks for asking, that's a good clarifying question! In my cypress console, I can see the real request going out, and responding with a status 200. In cypress browser, I can see that all the data has been fetched, and is displayed as intended. Now, there is an API key involved, so I updated my base URL to be more verbose by specifying the key, and the `wait` is still throwing the same error.

Comment: @nucleartux, wait a minute, I still had the interpolation of `${baseUrl}/games` which was improper formatting after adding in the api key. Fixing the url now has the stub working properly. Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use the correct protocol - `https://api.rawg.io/api`.

Second, there is nothing before the `https://api.rawg.io/api` so preceding with wildcard `**` is incorrect.

Third, put wildcards before or after path separator `/` or `//`.

Last, don't put an intercept in a `before()` because it is cleared between tests. Put it in `beforeEach()`

```js
describe("The Home Page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    // these all work (use only one)
    cy.intercept('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=my-key-goes-here').as('games')
    cy.intercept('**/api/games?key=my-key-goes-here').as('games')
    cy.intercept('**/api/games?*').as('games')
    cy.intercept('**/api/*').as('games')
    cy.intercept('**//api.rawg.io/api/*').as('games')
    cy.intercept({pathname: '**/api/*'}).as('games')
    cy.intercept({pathname: '**/api/games'}).as('games')

    cy.visit("/");
  });

  it("successfully loads", () => {
    cy.wait("@games")
      .its('response.body.count')
      .should('be.gt', 900000)
  })

  it("successfully loads again", () => {
    cy.wait("@games")
      .its('response.body.count')
      .should('be.gt', 900000)
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Tucker.Bowman! Yes, you made some important points (thanks for reminding me to fix the protocol!). This implementation is currently working for me. The real issue I was having was fixed by including the api key, which @nucleartux also helped with. Thanks for the help!